# Access to HttpContext.Current from message inspector for async WCF calls

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await, httpcontext

Preamble: in our app we have some logic based on custom message inspector. It parses WCF messages and set data (session or cookies) in current Http context over `HttpContext.Current`.
Situation: after switching to async WCF calls, we lost access to current context, which is `null` by now. I'm understanding that context actually saved and thread destroyed while `await` does his job, but maybe there's a way to fix this with less blood and without dangerous techniques?

Upd: here are some code. Sync ver:

```
public ActionResult Task()
{
//some logic
var result = ourService.DoCall();
//some logic
}
//in WCF message inspector
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
var request = HttpContext.Current; //got context here
}
```

Async ver:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Task()
{
//some logic
var result = await ourService.DoCallAsync();
//some logic
}
//in WCF message inspector
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
var request = HttpContext.Current; //got null
}
```

Comment: You can maintain context with async/await. Usually it means don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` when you must remain synchronization context aware. Are you using that? Are you abusing async with `Task.Run()`?

Comment: Nope. No abuse, no `Task.Run`, no .`ConfigureAwait(false)`. Just when I'm turning MVC action to async (and WCF calls inside too), message inspector getting null on `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: We hit the same problem lately. Have you ever found a solution? AFA our problem goes, the solution below does not apply since the context is lost on the caller side, not the service side. Also, we too don't use `ConfigureAwait` nor `Task.Run` in this stack of code. The problem seems to come from a call made by the continuation logic to `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory\`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func\`2 endFunction, Action\`1 endAction, Task\`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)` but we can't put the finger on why it's called.

Answer (score 0):

A little note on WCF, when hosting the WCF service running within an ASP.NET site, you need to enable aspnetCompatability mode, this can be done in the Wen.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Or individualy on the service level using

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorSession
{//Implement calculator service methods.}
```

You can check on the specifics from the [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-services-and-aspnet) page, this should give you more information about the mode.Enabling it will let WCF run under the ASP.NET pipeline instead of creating Modules to hook up to the events of the pipeline, this will also let you access the HttpContext object that is otherwise null if the setting is not enabled

A qoute from the referened article :

> HttpContext: Current is always null when accessed from within a WCF
>   service. Use RequestContext instead.

---

> The value of the RequestContext can be null. Because the role of the
>   request context is to link requests to replies, it does not make sense
>   to have a request context when you do not have a reply, and so in this
>   case the context is set to null. For a one-way operation on top of the
>   request/reply model, the server receives requests but does not send
>   back a response to the client. So if the RequestContext is null
>   unexpectedly, check first whether the operation contract is IsOneWay.

Qouted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.requestcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2

The Request context is null when a one way response is specified on the [OperationContract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2) header.

The RequestContext can be accessed by using

```
rcontext = operationContext.RequestContext
```

Comment: Service is not hosted within this ASP.NET site, it runs on another machine. Also there's a problem even with RequestContext  - we haven't it in our message inspector. The HttpContext.Current available only on non-async methods, in async cases it a `null` inside inspector.
Or you mean anything else?

Comment: The HttpContext will always be null if its not hosted in IIS and ASP.NET compatibility is enabled.

Comment: Where is the service hosted in that other machine?